Prove Decreasing Cross Entropy of outputs with Decreasing KL divergence of inputs
I am trying to prove the inequality $H(gt, y) > H(gt, y_1) > H(gt, y_2)$, given that $D_{KL}(x, x_1) > D_{KL}(x_1, x_2)$,
where $y = f(x)$, $gt$ - ground truth, $D_{KL}$ - KL divergence, $H$ is cross-entropy, and $f()$ is a monotonous function.
The assumption is that after smoothing $x$ to the level of $x_1$, the cross entropy loss of the classifier $f()$ decreases until the KL-divergence between smoothing stops decreasing.
I tried proving it by representing the cross entropy with the KL-divergence, but I always end up stuck at the initial $D_{KL}(x, x_1) > D_{KL}(x_1, x_2)$

I think you'll need to specify something about $D_{KL}(x,x_2)$, which could be arbitrarily small under your current assumptions: you could move away from $x$ to get $x_1$ then move nearly all the way back to get $x_2$.
